# lxml classic: Get text content except for that of nested tags?

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

This must be an absolute classic, but I can't find the answer here. I'm parsing the following tag with lxml cssselect:

```
<li><a href="/stations/1"><span class="num">3</span> Detroit</a></li>
```

I want to get the content of the `<li>` tag **without** the content of the `<span>` tag.

Currently I have:

```
stop_list = doc.cssselect('ol#stations li a')
start = stop_list[0].text_content().strip()
```

But that gives me `3 Detroit`. How can I just get `Detroit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertext` method of an element returns an iterator of node's text data. For your `<a>` tag, `' Detroit'` would be the 2nd value returned by the iterator. If structure of your document always conforms to a known specification, you could skip specific text elements to get what you need.

```
from lxml import html

doc = html.fromstring("""<li><a href="/stations/1"><span class="num">3</span> Detroit</a></li>""")
stop_nodes = doc.cssselect('li a') 
stop_names = []
for start in stop_list:
    node_text = start.itertext()
    node_text.next() # Skip '3'
    stop_names.append(node_text.next().lstrip())
    continue
```

You can combine css selector with the xpath `text()` function mentioned in [Zachary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141956/lxml-classic-get-text-content-except-for-that-of-nested-tags/8142269#8142269) like this (If you're more comfortable with using CSS selectors than xpath):

```
stop_names = [a.xpath('text()').lstrip() for a in doc.cssselect('li a')]
```

Answer (score 4):

For your example, I think going with XPath is cleaner and easier than CSS:

```
>>> xml = '<li><a href="/stations/1"><span class="num">3</span> Detroit</a></li>'
>>> root = etree.fromstring(xml)
>>> print( root.xpath('/li/a/text()'))
[' Detroit']

>>> xml = '<li><a href="/stations/1">I <span>FooBar!</span> love <span class="num">3</span> Detroit</a></li>'
>>> root = etree.fromstring(xml)
>>> print( root.xpath('/li/a/text()'))
['I ', ' love ', ' Detroit']

>>> ' '.join([x.strip() for x in root.xpath('/li/a/text()')])
'I love Detroit'
```