# Parsing XML from API response

Tags: python, xml, api

I've been trying for some hours to grab the response from the imgur API. I got the XML in the terminal, but I don't know how to grab it and parse it. Here's my code.

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
values = [
          ("key", "Super Secret API Number"),
          ("image", (c.FORM_FILE, "pic.jpg"))]

c.setopt(c.URL, "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.xml")
c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, values)
c.perform()
c.close()
```

I'm a big noob with python, this is my first time. Python virgin. I read that you can parse the xml with ElementTree, but I can't find any cool documentation.

Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: You could try using the nice python requests https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests when building http requests :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the response from `imgur-api` into a file.Than need to use a xml parser to parse the xml response/file you are getting from `Imgur-API`.

There are lots of option available like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Here is an example of how to use `lxml` with `XPath expressions`.

```
from lxml import etree


xml = """<foo>baz!</foo>"""

>>> xml = """<foo>baz!</foo>"""
>>> xp = etree.fromstring(xml)
>>> values = xp.xpath("//foo/text()")
>>> values
['baz!']
```

If you need to parse a xml file:

```
# parse from file
et = etree.parse(source_xml)
value = et.xpath("your xpath xpr here")
```

If you need to parse directly from url

```
# parse from URL
etree.parse("http://example.com/somefile.xml")
```

For, XPath use firefox's `firebug` extension or install `firepath`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't think about that, sounds logic.

Comment: @AlejandroAr: xpath is quite logical you can even try using `cssselect` with lxml. Use firebug to copy `csspath` of required element.

Answer (score 1):

When I started using the included ElementTree module I found the [documentation](http://file:///Users/zacharyyoung/Documents/html-docs/python-2.7.2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) lacking good examples (currently there are only 3, and only one of those shows anything immediately practical).

I've answered a couple of questions here on SO related to lxml/ElementTree, and I usually see people getting stuck trying to write these weird list comprehensions to deal with something XPath handles in one line much more clearly:

- [Parsing lxml.etree._Element contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729997/parsing-lxml-etree-element-contents/8730659#8730659)
- [lxml classic: Get text content except for that of nested tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141956/lxml-classic-get-text-content-except-for-that-of-nested-tags/8142269#8142269)

If you have a more specific question, please post some source XML and desired effect.

I hope this helps,